# TYPO3: Mails created from drafts are always sent to the same people

Tags: scheduled-tasks, typo3, newsletter

Im creating a newsletter (in a TYPO3 4.7.7 System using Direct Mail), where people register and for the next 15 days, each day they receive a different email.

for this I've created 15 different mailing lists, with a special query

```
SELECT uid,pid,deleted
FROM tt_address
WHERE ( (<current time stamp> - tstamp) > 86400*0
    AND (<current time stamp> - tstamp) < 86400*(<days from registration> + 1))
    AND tt_address.deleted=0
```

This works alright. The problem is that I need this process automatized, so I thought Id use the scheduler. I created 15 drafts, assigned to the corresponding mailing list. Then I would use the scheduler to create mails from the drafts.

The problem is that the mails that are being sent out everyday to the same people. I fear that the drafts saves a static list of email addresses, instead of recalculating the query every single day.

Is there any workaround to change this behaviour?

PS: I've found [a thread](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/34432#note-2) that comments on this problem, and delivers a patch for direct_mail 2.7. The problem is im running 3.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's a bug which is scheduled to be solved in version 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create test list and check it. I don't remember if DirectMail caches the e-mail addresses. In my opinion no. Check in database when you create new newsletter if there is a field with copied e-mail addressess.

Comment: The problem is real. I've found a thread about it. http://forge.typo3.org/issues/34432 They even submit a patch. The problem is that the patch is based on 2.7, and Im using 3.0.3